Apache Superset: How is it possible to create a Hierachie in a Pivot Table?
#Problem Description
I'm new to Apache Superset.
We have the following hierarchical structure (see below), and I need a Pivot Table be able to collapse and expand nodes like in other BI-Tools (such as SAP Analytics Cloud), to see the Sum of Sales on the different Levels. Also, we need to add and remove Columns as Requirements can be diverse.
Clarification: It is not enough to make just a very big Pivot Table, as this would defeat our Purpose of Simplification.
| STATE | REGION | STORE |SUM_SALES
#Question

Is there any possibility to do what I need to do with what is there?
Has anyone experience in how difficult it would be to write a
plugin to make that possible (via Viz Plugins)?

#This is what I tried

Use Filter
Tried out a SQL-Query as a Datasource for a Pivot Table

